# How do I recieve "cat" as my programs argumets?

Tags: c, binary, ascii, cat

I need to make a c program that will receive binary and output `ascii`,

I made the program and it works when I input `"s o m e t h i n g"` in to the program arguments and then the program outputs it as `ascii`.

But they require me to do

```
$cat "file" | ./"program"
```

when I do this nothing happens.

How do I catch this cat?

Is it not sent to my program as arguments?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to follow it.

Comment: short answer: man xargs
cat file | xargs ./program is (probably) what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The data is sent to your program's *standard input*.

You can read that directly from `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[1000];
    int n = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        printf("%d - %s", ++n, line); // line includes ENTER
    }
    return 0;
}
```